# How can I set multiline TextView Ellipsis properly in LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, textview

I have such a layout hierarchy as following:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title"
    android:background="#f00"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="title"
    />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/detail"
    android:background="#0f0"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="afasdfasdfasfasdfasfdasfasdfasfasdfsadfasfasdfasdfasdf"
    />

</LinearLayout>
```

The result view is like this:
[image]

The wrapper LinearLayout's height is going to be dynamically changed.So it is not fixed to 63dp.The fact is that the detail is being cut which doesn't satisfy my need.What I want is that the last complete visible line is changed to "XXX...".Like this:

[image]

From my code,I will change LinearLayout's height dynamically.

```
LinearLayout wrapper = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.wrapper);

wrapper.getLayoutParams().height = // dynamical height;
```

Comment: use one text view with maxlines and ellipsize and use spannable text 
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Spannable.html  
to change color

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to utilize the `maxLines` and `ellipsize` attributes.

```
<TextView
  android:id="@+id/detail"
  android:background="#0f0"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:maxLines="2"
  android:ellipsize="end"
  android:text="afasdfasdfasfasdfasfdasfasdfasfasdfsadfasfasdfasdfasdf"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `android:layout_height="63dp"` to  `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`